# GWT plugin not showing in eclipse

Tags: eclipse, gwt

I wanted old version of GWT plugin so I copied the entire eclipse folder from a colleague but it still not showing the GWT plugin in eclipse. I can see that it exist in the plugin folder inside eclipse.

Comment: What makes you think this could even work? To install something from another installation use _File > Import...: Install > From Existing Installation_. _"I wanted old version of GWT plugin"_ is the Y of your [XY problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem). The [GWT Plugin](https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/gwt-plugin) lists two update sites (hit the download icon) for the versions 3 and 4 of this plugin, each for different Eclipse versions: the GWT Plugin 3 update site for Eclipse 2021-12 (4.22) and lower and the GWT Plugin 4 update site for Eclipse 2022-09 (4.25) and higher.